# ssh dynamic application of ProxyJump based on network IP

Tags: ssh

I have a private git server in a private network, that is accessible via a proxy jump box.

*Problem:*  When I'm on the local network the proxy isn't needed as I can directly connect to the box.

Both situations use the same hostname.

*Question:* Is there a way to dynamically apply the ProxyJump configuration to the ssh command based on wether or not I'm on the network local to the git host?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Match exec` directive to check your network and enable ProxyJump in your `~/.ssh/config`

Here is the syntax:

```
Match host git.server !exec "ifconfig <nw adapter> | grep <local nw ip pattern>"
    ProxyJump user@<jump server>

Host server.git.com
    Hostname <git server ip>
```

Example:

```
Match host git.server !exec "ifconfig eth0 | grep 192.168.1.1"
    ProxyJump user@jumpserver

Host server.git.com
    Hostname 10.1.1.18
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to accomplish is a called a Bastion Host configuration. The configuration below uses SSH's `Match` directive combined with the `nc` command to detect connectivity to the remote host. If you are connected locally to the target host, no ProxyJump is used, otherwise, the connection to the remote host passes through the bastion host to establish the connection.

Note: This works on SSH v 7.3 and above and requires that the ssh daemon on the bastion host have AllowTcpForwarding enabled.

You need to configure your `~/.ssh/config` like so:

```
# Define the Bastion Host
Host bastion #this is a nickname. Call it what you want
    HostName host.example.com  # ip address or hostname
    Port 1234     # public facing SSH port
    User username # authorized username on the bastion host

# Remote host behind bastion
Host host-nickname
    HostName remote.internal.com # IP or hostname
    Port 5678                    # Only needed if not port 22
    User username                # authorized username on the remote

    # On linux, the output of nc is silent whether true or false
    # Match !exec "nc -z -w 1 %h %p"

    # On MacOS, nc prints data to STDOUT on success so suppress it
    # Also, -G 1 is needed on MacOS to timeout TCP connects after 1 second
    Match !exec "nc -z -w 1 -G 1 %h %p >/dev/null 2>&1"
    ProxyJump bastion
```

Note that all directives after the `Match` directive will be executed based on the truthiness of the `Match` directive. So you may decide to forward ports using the `LocalForward` directive before the `Match` directive (always map the port) or after (only map the port if Match is true).

`~/.ssh/config` is extremely versatile and powerful. Also this configuration allows your host directives and mappings to work in any connection management application or even on the command line by simply calling `ssh remote_host`. It is also portable (except for OS-specific `nc` command options) to any host that uses ssh (Windows, Linux, MacOS, etc). This method also allows for documenting things much better using comments in the config file which isn't possible in some connection managers.

There might even be a way to use a ternary operator to call the `nc` command using the right options for the OS, but I haven't tried it.

I replaced a very large and complicated iTerm2-only configuration with this method so that I can easily migrate back and forth from MacOS to Linux when I need to. This is useful since my connection manager (iTerm2) is now only used for color management and other UI-specific options.

For more info see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Passing_Through_One_or_More_Gateways_Using_ProxyJump

Comment: It turns out there is a one-liner ternary command that can be used for the 'nc' command. It is

[[ `uname -s` == 'Darwin' ]] && nc -z -w 1 -G 1 %h %p >/dev/null 2>&1 || nc -z -w 1 %h %p